# Does JavaScript run again when the browser retrieves a cached html page?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, caching

I have a html page that doesn't change too much and I want to cache it for one week for ex.
In this html I have some JS scripts that does some ajax requests and modifies the html.
When the browser loads this page, does the JS scripts run?

10x

Comment: Which html, provide the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea, it does.
JavaScript is always executed on page load, cached or not.

Unless you're postponing the JS with a `onload` handler, of course, then it's executed after the page's loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JS code runs each time the page is loaded.
As well, you can use onLoad event on body tag or jQuery event $(docuemnt).load(...).